# Get values from one function to another and calculate price

Tags: javascript

I have a range of days where price could be different that I have stored in an array and I have tried to calculate with a loop but I have troubles getting the input from the user and use those values in another function.

this is my code, I know is a little messy but it seems to fail when trying to get the check in and check out values that I store in the variables of the function getPrices

```js
/*Function to get the user input  -------------------------------*/ 
 
function checkIn_Calc(){

    checkIn_DateInput = document.getElementById("checkInDate").value;
    return new Date (checkIn_DateInput);
}

function checkOut_Calc(){

    checkOut_DateInput = document.getElementById("checkOutDate").value;
    return new Date (checkOut_DateInput);
}

/*function that updates when the user selects dates  -----------------------------------------*/ 

document.getElementById('checkInDate').addEventListener("change", getPrices);
document.getElementById('checkOutDate').addEventListener("change", getPrices);

function getPrices(event) {
   
    const day = 1000*60*60*24;
    return allSeasons.reduce( (totalPrice, season) => {
        let daysInSeason = Math.floor(
            (Math.min(+season.endDate+day,checkOut_Calc) 
             - Math.max(season.startDate, checkIn_Calc)) / day);
        return totalPrice + (daysInSeason > 0 && daysInSeason * season.costRate);
    }, 0);
} 

/* global variables for seasons  -------------------------------------------------------------------*/ 

const allSeasons = [
        {startDate: new Date(2021, 1-1, 1), endDate: new Date(2021, 4-1,30), costRate: 300},
        {startDate: new Date(2021, 5-1, 1), endDate: new Date(2021, 9-1,30), costRate: 400},
        {startDate: new Date(2021,10-1, 1), endDate: new Date(2021,12-1,31), costRate: 500}
    ]

    totalPrice = getPrices(allSeasons, checkOut_Calc, checkIn_Calc);
    console.log(totalPrice);
```

```html
<input type="date" id="checkInDate" />
<input type="date" id="checkOutDate" />
```

Comment: Thank you Kinglish, I noticed all the typo errors. I have updated my code and renamed all functions with clear names.  The only issue is that now I am getting 0 for total price. I think is because the input date is not getting the value from the function "checkIn_Calc" and "checkOut_Calc".   How can I declare a variable or pass the input dates to the function getPrices?

Answer (score 0):

better practice would be to use the event argument as "e",
and through that object get the value of the element.

Try:

```js
document
  .getElementById("checkInDate")
  .addEventListener("change", checkInDateResult);

function checkInDateResult(e) {
  checkInDateInput = e.target.value; 
  console.log(checkInDateInput);
  var checkInDate = new Date (checkInDateInput);
  console.log(checkInDate + " Input date");   
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="checkInDate" />
```

This worked for me, give it a shot :)

Answer (score 0):

First get rid of the top 2 event listeners. You don't need them and then you're defining them again (with different functions) below. You can't do that.

```
// delete these
document.getElementById('checkInDate').addEventListener("change", checkInDateResult);
document.getElementById('checkOutDate').addEventListener("change", checkOutDateResult);
```

Then for `getPrices`, the only argument it will have is `event`. You can get rid of the 3 you have in there

`function getPrices(allSeasons, checkInInput, checkOutPut) {`
becomes..
`function getPrices(event) {`

`allSeasons` is an array available globally.

Then, don't use the same variable for 2 different things.

```
var checkin = checkInDateResult(); 
var checkout = checkOutDateResult(); // typo: checkOutDaTeResult
```

.. which means, those 2 functions need to `return` the date

```
function checkOutDateResult(){
    checkOutDateInput = document.getElementById("checkOutDate").value;
    return new Date (checkOutDateInput);
}
```

.. and do the same thing to `checkInDateResult`